# Ubuntu 18.04 does not remember audio device

Tags: sound, 18.04

i have multiple audio devices, but i am using 1 of them 99% of the time. 
If I boot/restart my machine, it says that the current playing device is "something" while the sound comes from last used device ( which is fine ).

However if I use my volume up/down keys ( from my mouse ) or top right corner slider, it changes the volume of another device, so the result is ... none. So i have to manually set default audio device after every system boot, than changing volume works normal.
Back in 16.04 it was all fine.

I wonder if someone can help me fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue! Super annoying after upgrade

Comment: Same issue here